# How can I input UTF-8 char in Android SearchView

Tags: android, utf-8, searchview

I can not input char in UTF-8 in SearchView. 
How can I fix it?

My language is Vietnamese 
I use virtual machine by Android Studio (Pixel 6 - API 28)

**My SearchView .xml code**

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_search_bar"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="nhập gì đó để chúng tìm"
    tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

</SearchView>
```

I also implement Vietnamese in language setting of VM but it still not work.

**my input:** "`caanw hooj`"

**current result:** `searchview.query == "Cn h"`

**expect:** `searchview.query == "Căn hộ"` (it's meaning apartment)

Comment: By "my input" do you mean you physically type that on a keyboard (or on-screen keyboard)? If so, then maybe something is weird about the IME setup.

Comment: yes, that 100% my physically type